# How to filter uploads with express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am trying to make a file uploading site using express-fileupload but I cant find a way to filter files by extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by checking the mime type. You can use [this npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime) to help you

Example code:

```
var mime = require("mime")
mime.getType('txt.png'); // return image/png type
```

Comment: using POSTMAN like this response.json({
    file: file.mimetype,
  });

Answer (score 1):

express-fileupload returns file mime type in mimetype field.
You can filter by mime type.